# How to access latitude and longitude in a script with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get latitude and longitude from a webpage using beautifulsoup but they are in a script:

```
//<![CDATA[

theForm.oldSubmit = theForm.submit;
theForm.submit = WebForm_SaveScrollPositionSubmit;

theForm.oldOnSubmit = theForm.onsubmit;
theForm.onsubmit = WebForm_SaveScrollPositionOnSubmit;
var GMapsProperties={};function getGMapElementById(mapId,GMapElementId){var _mapId=typeof(mapId)=='string'? mapId : mapId.getDiv().id;var overlayArray=GMapsProperties[_mapId]['overlayArray'];for(var i=0;i < overlayArray.length;i++){if(overlayArray[i][0]==GMapElementId){return overlayArray[i][1];}}return null;}function removeGMapElementById(mapId,GMapElementId){var _mapId=typeof(mapId)=='string'? mapId : mapId.getDiv().id;var overlayArray=GMapsProperties[_mapId]['overlayArray'];for(var i=0;i < overlayArray.length;i++){if(overlayArray[i][0]==GMapElementId){overlayArray.splice(i,1);return;}}}function closeWindows(mapId){for(var i=0;i<GMapsProperties[mapId]['windowArray'].length;i++){GMapsProperties[mapId]['windowArray'][i][1].close();}}var _sg=_sg ||{};_sg.cs=(function(){var p={};p.createMarker=function(opt,id){var m=new google.maps.Marker(opt);if(id && m.getMap())GMapsProperties[m.getMap().getDiv().id]['overlayArray'].push([id,m]);return m;};p.createPolyline=function(opt,id){var m=new google.maps.Polyline(opt);if(id && m.getMap())GMapsProperties[m.getMap().getDiv().id]['overlayArray'].push([id,m]);return m;};p.createPolygon=function(opt,id){var m=new google.maps.Polygon(opt);if(id && m.getMap())GMapsProperties[m.getMap().getDiv().id]['overlayArray'].push([id,m]);return m;};return p;})();function addEvent(el,ev,fn){if(el.addEventListener)el.addEventListener(ev,fn,false);else if(el.attachEvent)el.attachEvent('on'+ev,fn);else el['on'+ev]=fn;}GMapsProperties['subgurim_GoogleMapControl'] = {}; var GMapsProperties_subgurim_GoogleMapControl = GMapsProperties['subgurim_GoogleMapControl']; GMapsProperties_subgurim_GoogleMapControl['enableStore'] = false; GMapsProperties_subgurim_GoogleMapControl['overlayArray'] = new Array(); GMapsProperties_subgurim_GoogleMapControl['windowArray'] = new Array();var subgurim_GoogleMapControl;function load_subgurim_GoogleMapControl(){var mapDOM = document.getElementById('subgurim_GoogleMapControl'); if (!mapDOM) return;subgurim_GoogleMapControl = new google.maps.Map(mapDOM);function subgurim_GoogleMapControlupdateValues(eventId,value){var item=document.getElementById('subgurim_GoogleMapControl_Event'+eventId);item.value=value;}google.maps.event.addListener(subgurim_GoogleMapControl, 'addoverlay', function(overlay) { if(overlay) { GMapsProperties['subgurim_GoogleMapControl']['overlayArray'].push(overlay); } });google.maps.event.addListener(subgurim_GoogleMapControl, 'clearoverlays', function() { GMapsProperties['subgurim_GoogleMapControl']['overlayArray'] = new Array(); });google.maps.event.addListener(subgurim_GoogleMapControl, 'removeoverlay', function(overlay) { removeGMapElementById('subgurim_GoogleMapControl',overlay.id) });google.maps.event.addListener(subgurim_GoogleMapControl, 'maptypeid_changed', function() { var tipo = subgurim_GoogleMapControl.getMapTypeId(); subgurim_GoogleMapControlupdateValues('0', tipo);});google.maps.event.addListener(subgurim_GoogleMapControl, 'dragend', function() { var lat = subgurim_GoogleMapControl.getCenter().lat(); var lng = subgurim_GoogleMapControl.getCenter().lng(); subgurim_GoogleMapControlupdateValues('2', lat+','+lng); });google.maps.event.addListener(subgurim_GoogleMapControl, 'zoom_changed', function() { subgurim_GoogleMapControlupdateValues('1', subgurim_GoogleMapControl.getZoom()); });subgurim_GoogleMapControl.setOptions({center:new google.maps.LatLng(35.6783546483511,51.4196634292603),disableDefaultUI:true,keyboardShortcuts:false,mapTypeControl:false,mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,scrollwheel:false,zoom:14});var marker_subgurim_920435_=_sg.cs.createMarker({position:new google.maps.LatLng(35.6783546483511,51.4196634292603),clickable:true,draggable:false,map:subgurim_GoogleMapControl,raiseOnDrag:true,visible:true,icon:'/images/markers/Site/Tourism/vase.png'}, 'marker_subgurim_920435_');}addEvent(window,'load',load_subgurim_GoogleMapControl);//]]>
```

and I want information in this part:

```
{position:new google.maps.LatLng(35.6783546483511,51.4196634292603)
```

is it possible to access that information by using beautifulsoup or any other web-scraper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for this purpose.

```
import re
#Suppose script is stored in variable script_file
m = re.search('LatLng(\(.+?\))', script_file)

latlng = m.group(1)
latlng = eval(latlng)
print(latlng) #(35.6783546483511, 51.4196634292603)
```

Comment: can you explain more how can I use Regular expression?

Comment: i store the script to script_file but when I ran the python script i got this error:latlng = eval(latlng)
  File "<string>", line 1
    (3
     ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: @Mehdi There was a syntax error now try it its working.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
s = 'position:new google.maps.LatLng(35.6783546483511,51.4196634292603)'
lat, lng = map(float, re.search(r'\(([^,]+),([^)]+)', s).groups())
```

Comment: thank you @simleo, but is there any way to take the "s" from the html code?
I have to use it for  about 100 hundred pages

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get Latitude and Longitude separately, use [regex expression](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html?highlight=re#module-re) in this way:

```
import re

s = 'position:new google.maps.LatLng(35.6783546483511,51.4196634292603)' 

Lat, Lng = map(float, re.search(r'LatLng\(([\d.]+),([\d.]+)\)',s).groups())
```